# Android ,overlapping imageview android

Tags: imageview

I tried to display a small imageview above the big imageview .It worked fine.
But when I made the small imageview to appear in rounded shape, It is not showing up.. Your reply will be helpful

there is no error or warning or any crashing of avd .simply the small imageview is not showing

.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="1000dp"
        android:maxWidth="1000dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ciaz"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ac"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />
</RelativeLayout>

mainactivity.java

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        im2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



        im1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            try
            {
                int action=arg1.getAction();
                float x=(float)arg1.getX();
                float y=(float)arg1.getY();


                if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    context = getApplicationContext();
                    duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    String g= x+"  "+y;


                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, g, duration);
                    toast.show();

                    if((x>0.0) && (x<100)&&(y>0.0) && (y<100))
                    {
                        im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ac);
                        roundedImage = new RoundedImageView(bm);
                        im2.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
                  }


                }

                }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "exception", duration);
                toast.show();
            }
            return false;
            }
        });


    }

enter code here
```

Comment: Are you using relative layout to overlap imageview ?

Comment: yes i m using relative layout

Comment: Please check my answer and if it solve ur problem please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you are using relative layout, place big image view first and then after small age view. Otherwise big image view overlaps small image view. If that is not the case can u please give code snippet to help more and find out the issue ?
You are giving 1000 h and 1000 w for first image view, and using android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1" in second imageview. So it goes out of ur device screen. Use match parent for first image view and remove alignbottom.

Comment: Please check above answer.

Comment: how to match parent in first image ? could you please explain?

Comment: Please give me screen shot or rough paint, what type of view you want to achieve? So that i can help you. Also please attach screen shot of your current view.